# Can I UPDATE multiple records using different values in a SELECT query?

Tags: sql

For example I have `table1` with `field1` and `field2` and want to do something like:

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1, field2 = (SELECT field1, field 2 FROM tableXYZ)
WHERE field 3 = 'foobar'
```

or do I have to do multiple SETs, running the same SELECT query several times?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should probably just try before asking on SO.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: You seem to have correct answer within the question itself.  Did you even try executing it? You could even add a where conditions inside a (Select field1 , field2 from tableXYZ where something='something')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming whatever database you are using supports it, you can join the tables. SO:

```
Update table1
set field1 = tbx.field1,
field2 = tbx.field2
from table1 join tablexyz on --some key value join
```

Comment: Thus I added 'whatever database you are using supports it'

Answer (score 0):

You can do a tuple assignment by putting the columns on the left hand side between parentheses.

```
UPDATE table1
  SET (column1, column2) = (SELECT col1, col2 
                            FROM tableXYZ
                            WHERE ...)
WHERE column3 = 'foobar';
```

The above is standard SQL, but not all DBMS support that.

Note that you **have** to use a `WHERE` clause in the sub-select to make sure that select only returns a **single** row (you would typically make that a co-related sub-query).